# How to access variable from outside class in another file

Tags: ruby

My file structure is as follows:

```
Main/
Games/ 
   roulette.rb
casino.rb
wallet.rb
player.rb
```

I have a wallet class that holds a money value in the class like so.

```
class Wallet
    attr_accessor :money
    def initialize
        @money = 0
    end
end
```

I then have a player class that inherits from the Wallet class

```
class Player < Wallet

    attr_accessor :name
    def initialize
        super()
        @name = nil
        get_user_info
    end
```

I then have a Casino class that inherits from Player like so

```
class Casino < Player
    def initialize
        binding.pry
        puts @money, @name
    end
```

I have also used `require_relative` to pull in both files thinking that would give me access to their global variables `@money, @name`.

If I am inside the `roulette.rb` file here is my code I wrote just to see if it would have a value.

```
require_relative '../wallet.rb'

class Roulette
    def initialize
        puts @wallet
    end
end
```

How would I go about getting access to these variables in the casino class? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok sorry, edited the original

Comment: Aside from your actual question, this seems like a major misuse of inheritance. If class `A` inherits from class `B`, then it should make sense to say "A is a type of B". In this case, is a Player a type of Wallet? No. Is a Casino a type of Player? No. I'd advise rethinking your class architecture.

Comment: Yea so wallet inherits from player, and casino inherits from player, so I just called super from casino to instantiate each class. Which creates the wallet.

Comment: @DanielBailey "which creates the wallet" - again, not quite. "casino = Casino.new". This `casino` is a casino and a player and a wallet, all three in the same single object. I agree with Tom Lord, this is a misuse of inheritance. There's no chance this is needed in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not global variables. They are called "instance variables" and to access them you need to create instances of your casinos and players. Looks like this.

```
player = Player.new
player.money # => 0
player.money += 10
player.money # => 10
```

In your Casino class you don't call parent initializers (a simple oversight, I think), so it doesn't initialize `@name` and `@money`.

And Roulette doesn't do anything at all to obtain a wallet. So it stays at default value nil.

Comment: yea JS lingo I can't drop ha. Ok so I am creating an instance of the wallet inside of the player, and creating an instance of the casino inside of the player. How would I get access to those instance variables inside of casino?

Comment: @DanielBailey: "I am creating an instance of the wallet inside of the player" - no you don't. In your hierarchy a casino IS a player, which is ALSO a wallet. Doesn't make any sense, right? :)

Comment: yea I'm so lost. Only a week in learning ruby, so struggling with how each class inherits what. Guess I need to do more reading

Comment: @DanielBailey: "How would I get access to those instance variables inside of casino" - call super in casino's initializer, this should set name/money.

Comment: @DanielBailey: yeah, JS object model does that to people :) Look up a book called "practical object-oriented design in ruby" (AKA POODR). It's excellent. Might be overwhelming at first (at your skill level), but on a second or third read you'll get a level-up, guaranteed :)

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. I removed the Player.new and Wallet.new that I had buried in my code. Then called super() on the casino class which inherited from player, which inherited from wallet. I now have access to all the wallet methods on casino. Sweet Thanks dude! Getting closer to what I want now

Comment: I need some more help if you don't mind. Is there a direct message feature?

Comment: @DanielBailey "Is there a direct message feature?" - nope, and on purpose. Buuut, you can hire me on codementor. :)